# Get the name of label inside Radio box

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html component

```
<div class='clearfix gbo' id='11tonne_truck' data-capaciteit='11 tonne truck'>
    <div style='float: left;' class='bb'><img class='tic' src='<?php echo base_url(' assets/images/map_icons/truck_3.svg '); ?>'></div>
    <div style='float: left;' class='economy'>10 Tonne Truck</div>
    <div style='float: right;' class='infuhr'>
        <ion-icon class='ic' name='information-circle-outline' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='lorem ipsum'></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div style='float: right;' class='bb transport_amount' id='11tonne_truck_amount'>Ksh 250 <br/> <span class='pt' id='11tonne_truck_pt'>Pickup by 00:00 pm</span></div>
    <div class='typesd'>
        <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='any' checked>Any</label>
        <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='closed'>Closed</label>
        <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='open'>Open</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

and i want to get the the label that holds the radio button. I have tried this

```
$('input:radio[name="optradio"]').change(function() {
    var selectedText = $('label').closest('.radio-inline').text();
    var selectedCapacity = $('.gbo').closest('#11tonne_truck').attr('data-capaciteit');
    alert(selectedText);    
    alert(selectedCapacity);
});
```

and this is the result http://jsfiddle.net/ay8z749k/10/

I am only getting the entire set of radio boxes but i am only interested in the value of the clicked radio button.
How can i the correct value of `selectedText`

Comment: Use `console.log($(this).text());` inside the handler.

Comment: Change $('label') to $(this) for the changed element

Comment: duplicated IDs are an issue...

Comment: I am trying this `var selectedCapacity = $(this).attr('data-capaciteit');` and i get undefined. How can i get the value of data when i click the radio button?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` keyword to get changed input inside the handler. To get parent `<label>` tag use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. So, the following code will show text of selected radio button.

```js
$('input:radio[name="optradio"]').change(function() {
  var $input=$(this);
  console.log('The value is ' + $input.val());
  console.log('The label text is ' + $input.closest('label').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='clearfix gbo' id='11tonne_truck' data-capaciteit='11 tonne truck'>
  <div style='float: left;' class='bb'><img class='tic' src='<?php echo base_url(' assets/images/map_icons/truck_3.svg '); ?>'></div>
  <div style='float: left;' class='economy'>10 Tonne Truck</div>
  <div style='float: right;' class='infuhr'>
    <ion-icon class='ic' name='information-circle-outline' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='lorem ipsum'></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div style='float: right;' class='bb transport_amount' id='11tonne_truck_amount'>Ksh 250
    <br/> <span class='pt' id='11tonne_truck_pt'>Pickup by 00:00 pm</span></div>
  <div class='typesd'>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
      <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='any' checked>Any
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
      <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='closed'>Closed
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
      <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='open'>Open
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way is to attach listener to a `<label>`. The trick uses [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). Therefore, in the following snippet `this` will reference to `<label>`, that includes changed input.

```
$('label').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```